# Solspace Reset Password Error 'The code number you submitted was not found in the database'

Tags: error, solspace-user, forgot-password

I am using Solpaces User module (v4.0.9) on a recent EE build (v3.5.10) and the reset password feature is throwing up the following error:

**The code number you submitted was not found in the database.**

This message appears on a system message page and I'm struggling to figure out why this is happening. Everything works quite smoothly up until that point. The reset email comes through and the link takes me to the right place. Its only when I type in my new password and confirm it do I get this error.

Can anybody shed any light on why it might be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is install and check out the Demo Templates that come included with User. Doing so will let you see a correct usage of the User template tags and possibly help you track down where there might be an issue with your own templates. We would otherwise need to see your template code and get more information before we're able to help. :)